# Dagger does not override module as expected

Tags: java, testing, dependency-injection, mockito, dagger

I'm using Square's Dagger v1.0.1 for dependency injection and I cannot make *overrides = true* to work as expected.

I have a provider class for test named *MyGameTestModule.java* :

```
@Module(
        includes = { BaseModule.class, NetModule.class},
        injects = { MyGame.class, MyManager.class },
        overrides = true
)
public class MyGameTestModule {

    // ...

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    DummyInterface provideDummyInterface() {
        return new DummyInterface() {
            @Override
            public Bar getBar() {
                // return actual Bar
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And I have a test like this named *MyManagerTest.java* :

```
public class MyManagerTest {
    @Inject
    public MyManager myManager;

    // ...

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        ObjectGraph objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new TestModule());
        objectGraph.inject(this);
    }

    @Module(
        includes = {MyGameTestModule.class}, 
        injects = {MyManagerTest.class}, 
        overrides = true
    )
    public static class TestModule {
        @Provides
        @Singleton
        DummyInterface provideDummyInterface() {
            return new DummyInterface() {
                @Override
                public Bar getBar() {
                    // return mocked Bar
                }
            };
        }
    }     
}
```

But when I run my tests, Dagger throws an exception like this:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate:
>       com.foo.DummyInterface com.foo.MyManagerTest$TestModule.provideDummyInterface()
>       com.foo.DummyInterface com.foo.MyGameTestModule.provideDummyInterface()   at
>   dagger.internal.UniqueMap.put(UniqueMap.java:29)  at
>   dagger.internal.plugins.reflect.ReflectiveModuleAdapter.handleBindings(ReflectiveModuleAdapter.java:104)
>     at
>   dagger.internal.plugins.reflect.ReflectiveModuleAdapter.getBindings(ReflectiveModuleAdapter.java:89)
>     at
>   dagger.ObjectGraph$DaggerObjectGraph.makeGraph(ObjectGraph.java:174)
>     at
>   dagger.ObjectGraph$DaggerObjectGraph.access$000(ObjectGraph.java:132)
>     at dagger.ObjectGraph.create(ObjectGraph.java:129)  at
>   com.foo.MyManagerTest.setup(MyManagerTest.java:38)

Am I missing something? Isn't it supposed to override DummyInterface in MyGameTestModule with *"overrides = true"* provided to *Module*?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using 1.0.1? There's 1.2.2 out there, maybe the problem is solved in this version.

Comment: I've tried 1.2.2 but had to deal with a bunch of different kinds of problems. I was just wondering if there is something wrong with the way I'm using *overrides=true*

Answer (score 0):

Use `addsTo` instead of `includes` in `TestModule`:

```
@Module(
    addsTo = {MyGameTestModule.class}, 
    injects = {MyManagerTest.class}, 
    overrides = true
)
public static class TestModule {
}
```

And create `ObjectGraph` with both `MyGameTestModule` and `TestModule`:

```
ObjectGraph.create(new MyGameTestModule(), new TestModule());
```

Comment: I've tried this, however dagger kept throwing *duplicate* exceptions.

Comment: Just noticed that you have `overrides = true` at `MyGameTestModule` class. Do you really need that? Cause dagger modules can be overriden only once. By the way it is not actually overriding, but shadowing.